# Rank individuals of population after multi objective optimization using MCDM algorithm

Tags: multi-objective-optimization, multicriteria-decision-analysis

I am trying to solve a multi objective optimization problem. It has 5 objectives. I am able to do optimization using NSGA2 algorithm of `pymoo` library in python. After that I want to fetch top N individuals from the optimal offspring/ individual population.

NSGA2 provides pareto optimal solutions. These are trade off solutions where none of the individual solution dominates any other solution. Finally we need to find a decision point. In my case I want to find N decision points.

For now I have thought of using Topsis algorithm in `pymcdm` to rank the individual solutions and then take the top N individuals. Is this approach correct ?

Comment: As far as I remember, the TOPSIS method can be used when we have some predefined criteria and ranking them based on. The multi-objective optimization uses some other methods like weighted, lexicographical, $\epsilon$-constraint, etc. to get the Pareto frontier in an efficient manner when the criteria are defined based on the decision variables.

Comment: I have updated my question with additional details. Since I am using NSGA2 algorithm, I assume it will already give pareto frontier. I want to find top N solution from those non dominated points in pareto front.

Comment: I am not sure to understand `to find top N solution from those non-dominated points`. Actually, there is no difference between these points, and this is why they are called non-dominated solutions. However, I am not sure ranking these solutions to select a few of them to be a worthwhile thing. B.T.W if you want to do this you can define some criteria on the whole frontier solution and go ahead with TOPSIS steps.

Comment: Thanks Omidi. Suppose I want to find top N points based on absolute value of second criteria out of five criteria. How can that be done using Topsis ? Would you be kind enough to reply ?

Comment: Also if Topsis won't serve that purpose, can you direct me towards any other alternative approach.

Comment: This is a long time since I used TOPSIS to select a project. So many things may be missed. Supposed you have five non-dominated solutions. You need to define some new criteria, apart from defined on the objectives, and also weighing these new criteria. Then apply TOPSIS steps to sort these solutions based on the new criteria. In the end, select the top $\text{N}$ solutions. I hope it helps.